# ¿Cuál es la forma correcta de hacer una consulta con find() en la versión actual de Mongoose?

Tags: nodejs, mongoose

Anteriormente las consultas las realizaba de la siguiente forma:

```
Modelo.find({dato:'foo'},function(error, resultado){

});
```

Sin embargo, la documentación v4.9.4, a mi parecer, es muy enredada y muestra que se debe realizar de la siguiente manera:

```
let query = Modelo.find({dato:'foo'}).exec();
```

y posteriormente hacer la integración de los promises.

¿Es esa la **única** forma correcta? ¿Es correcto seguir usando la sintaxis anterior? ¿Existe blog o documento alguno que muestre un resumen mas claro de la documentación?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ¿Es esa la **única** forma correcta?

No es la única forma correcta; de ninguna manera. Usar callbacks o promesas es cuestión de cultura del programador y ésta es la que influirá en el uso de uno u otro enfoque.

Personalmente te recomiendo usar promesas. ¿Por qué? Por la simple razón es base para nuevos estándares como [Async/Await](https://github.com/tc39/ecmascript-asyncawait) e [Import()](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) (Extensión de `import` que devuelve una promesa con el módulo, permitiendo importar módulos cuando queramos). El código legacy se está migrando a ES6+ por la gran flexibilidad y las posibilidades que te ofrece de escribir un código mejor y más conciso.

> ¿Es correcto seguir usando la sintaxis anterior?

Como te dije en el punto anterior, es cuestión de cultura del programador. Los callbacks jamás pasarán de moda porque son un pilar del código asíncrono. Puedes usar callbacks o *usar un enfoque más moderno*, como son las promesas y async/await.

Imagina que tienes tres llamadas consecutivas:

```
Model.find({ ... }, (err, docs) => {
  docs.map(doc => {
    doc.disabled = false;
    doc.save((err, _doc) => {
      OtherModel.findByOnwer(_doc._id, (err, docs) => {
       docs.forEach(doc => doc.populate('campo').execPopulate((err, _docs) => {
          // y cada vez más profundo
        });
      });
    });
```

Esto se llama [*callback hell*](http://callbackhell.com/) y es un problema muy común que lamentablemente hace del código muy difícil de leer, de entender y aún más, de mantener. Afortunadamente, las promesas nos ayudan más que todo, **semánticamente**, reducen la carga cognitiva del código y te hace escribir un código de alguna manera, más agradable.

```
Model
  .find({ ... })
  .then(value => {
    ...
  })
  .then(newValue => {
    ...
  });
```

Con la llegada de `async/await`, tu código incluso se ve como si fuese síncrono:

```
const docs = await Model.find({ ... }).populate('field');
return docs;
```

Otro ejemplo es la nueva propuesta `Import()`:

```
const modulo = await import('./fichero');
// acceso al módulo como si usases CommonJS (require)
```

---

Siempre que te sea posible, usa ES6+, incluso cuando no puedas, úsalo y lo compilas a ES5 mediante https://babeljs.io.

---

**PD:** A partir de Node.js 7.8 ya es posible usar `async/await` nativamente.